# Algorithm to convert 2d image to 3d image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, dimension

For research purpose, is there any existing algorithm that can transform 2d image to 3d models? For example, transforming a circle into sphere or transforming an image of apple into 3d model of apple. Simple algorithm or imperfect algorithm is fine too. If there isn’t, what are the fields or areas that I should take a look into to know more about it?

Comment: An accurate 3D reconstruction of an object would require multiple images of the object. It's possible to generate a 3-dimensional depth map using [monocular depth estimation](https://medium.com/toyotaresearch/monocular-depth-in-the-real-world-99c2b287df34) from a single image, but the depth map won't necessarily be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth searching here http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/code.html
There are the sources of 2D-to-3D propcessing algorithm based on the conception of neural networks. This project was introduced by **prof. Andrew Ng** team.

Video demo of conversion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&amp=&v=GWWIn29ZV4Q